# Stacked Modal in ionic 6 without Backdrop

Tags: ionic-framework, modal-dialog, ionic6

I try to add a backdrop to my stacked modal (ionic 6) with a smaller size then the first opened, like here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/modal

and put this:

```
ion-modal.stack-modal { 
 --box-shadow: 0 28px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4); 
 --backdrop-opacity: var(--ion-backdrop-opacity, 0.32);
}
```

in my global.scss.

Now I’m opening my Modal with:

```
const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
      component: StackedModalPage,
      cssClass: 'stack-modal',
      componentProps: {
```

But it’s not working for me, the smaller Modal opens without any backdrop.

Comment: `showBackdrop: true` to your modal options.

Comment: no effect, I also tried the first big modal with showBackdrop:false and the stacked with showBackrop:true, but also no effect

Comment: can you make stackblitz example?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ionic-6-david-lnzwrf?file=src/app/app.component.html - Sorry but I'd to fork another one, because I'm not really familiar with ionic in stackblitz: Just make the space for the page a little wider so the fullscreen and normal size can be displayed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As found here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/backdrop-for-stack-modal/222468

Try using `!important`

```
ion-modal.stack-modal { 
 --box-shadow: 0 28px 48px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) !important; 
 --backdrop-opacity: var(--ion-backdrop-opacity, 0.32) !important;
}
```

Are you by any chance the "basti" user on the referenced forum?

Comment: yes, thanks for referencing this here!